# Java exception error using MATLAB vrml

Tags: java, matlab, animation, 3d, vrml

The following exception error occurs when I try to add a transform node in the 3D World Editor in MATLAB and it's driving me crazy:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.mathworks.toolbox.sl3d.icons.SL3DIcon.TREE_EXPOSEDFİELD

Does anyone know how to resolve this error? I have already tried reinstalling MATLAB and Java. I am using Windows 10, and a 64 bit version of MATLAB.

Comment: If any 3d party code is added to your search path, remove it temporarily to test if the error is caused by that code. If it still occurs with a blank Matlab installation, I recommend to contact the Mathworks Support. This is likely to be a bug in Matlab.

Comment: It is very interesting that my roommate can work it out perfectly despite the fact that our computers are identical to each other in operating systems and java configurations as well.

Comment: Are your roommate using the same version of matlab as well? Anyway, if you use windows and have reinstalled Matlab, then everything should work. I am not completely sure how the Matlab installer work, for example if it can use libraries from older Matlab versions as well (which would be unlikely and imo not very good). Anyway in nine cases out of ten this is a bug. Matlab obviously tries to access an enum which is not defined. It looks like something have been forgotten in the java code. You should write a bug report to Matlab. #neverusedefault

Comment: Yes he is using the same version of Matlab. When I tried to install Vrealm editor instead of the default editor, Built-in 3D, it worked. So I agree with #neverusedefault